# Сохранение данных в куки

Tags: javascript, html, cookie

Как сохранить имя пользователя в куки из инпута?

```html
<form name="userName" method="post" action="input1.php">
  <p>
    <b>Для начала игры введите ваше имя:</b><br>
    <input type="text" size="33">
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: На какое событие? При отправки формы?  При изминении? И в чем конкретно у вас загвоздка

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку, например такую: <a href="#" class="startGameButton"/>Начать игру</a>, должна идти читка и сохранение введенной строки с импута в файлы куки

Comment: Нашёл классную библиотеку для реализации в 2 клика: https://tokar.ua/read/5822

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  function setCookie(name, value, options) {
      options = options || {};
      var expires = options.expires;

      if (typeof expires == "number" && expires) {
          var d = new Date();
          d.setTime(d.getTime() + expires * 1000);
          expires = options.expires = d;
      }
      if (expires && expires.toUTCString) {
          options.expires = expires.toUTCString();
      }

      value = encodeURIComponent(value);

      var updatedCookie = name + "=" + value;

      for (var propName in options) {
          updatedCookie += "; " + propName;
          var propValue = options[propName];
          if (propValue !== true) {
              updatedCookie += "=" + propValue;
          }
       }

      document.cookie = updatedCookie;
}
var nickName = document.getElementById('nickName');
var button = document.getElementsByClass('startGameButton')[0];

button.addEventListener('click', setCookie('nick_name', nickName.value));
```

Добавьте к Input id="nickName".